# Istio DestinationRule subset label not found on matching host

Tags: istio

I'm trying to configure an Istio `VirtialService` / `DestinationRule` so that a grpc call to the service from a pod labeled `datacenter=chi5` is routed to a grpc server on a pod labeled `datacenter=chi5`.

I have Istio 1.4 installed on a cluster running Kubernetes 1.15.

A `route` is **not** getting created in `istio-sidecar` envoy config for the `chi5` subset and traffic is being routed round robin between each service endpoint regardless of pod label.

Kiali is reporting an error in the `DestinationRule` config: "this subset's labels are not found in any matching host".

Do I misunderstand the functionality of these Istio traffic management objects or is there an error in my configuration?

I believe my pod's are correctly labeled:

```sh
$ (dev) kubectl get pods -n istio-demo --show-labels
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    LABELS
ticketclient-586c69f77d-wkj5d   2/2     Running   0          158m   app=ticketclient,datacenter=chi6,pod-template-hash=586c69f77d,run=client-service,security.istio.io/tlsMode=istio
ticketserver-7654cb5f88-bqnqb   2/2     Running   0          158m   app=ticketserver,datacenter=chi5,pod-template-hash=7654cb5f88,run=ticket-service,security.istio.io/tlsMode=istio
ticketserver-7654cb5f88-pms25   2/2     Running   0          158m   app=ticketserver,datacenter=chi6,pod-template-hash=7654cb5f88,run=ticket-service,security.istio.io/tlsMode=istio
```

The port-name on my k8s Service object is correctly prefixed with the `grpc` protocol:

```sh
$ (dev) kubectl describe service -n istio-demo ticket-service
Name:              ticket-service
Namespace:         istio-demo
Labels:            app=ticketserver
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          run=ticket-service
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.234.14.53
Port:              grpc-ticket  10000/TCP
TargetPort:        6001/TCP
Endpoints:         10.37.128.37:6001,10.44.0.0:6001
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

I've deployed the following Istio objects to Kubernetes:

```
Kind:         VirtualService
Name:         ticket-destinationrule
Namespace:    istio-demo
Labels:       app=ticketserver
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
Kind:         DestinationRule
Spec:
  Host:  ticket-service.istio-demo.svc.cluster.local
  Subsets:
    Labels:
      Datacenter:  chi5
    Name:          chi5
    Labels:
      Datacenter:  chi6
    Name:          chi6
Events:            <none>
---
Name:         ticket-virtualservice
Namespace:    istio-demo
Labels:       app=ticketserver
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
Kind:         VirtualService
Spec:
  Hosts:
    ticket-service.istio-demo.svc.cluster.local
  Http:
    Match:
      Name:  ticket-chi5
      Port:  10000
      Source Labels:
        Datacenter:  chi5
    Route:
      Destination:
        Host:    ticket-service.istio-demo.svc.cluster.local
        Subset:  chi5
Events:          <none>
```

Comment: The above example works correctly with 1.6.8 deployed to the cluster.  I'm not going to submit an answer, since I don't understand why this didn't work with 1.4, but if you come across a similar problem I suggest upgrading Istio control-plane if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have made reproduction of your issue with 2 nginx pods.

What you want to have can be achieved with [sourceLabel](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPFaultInjection-Delay),check below example, I think it explain everything.

For start I made 2 ubuntu pods, 1 with [label app:ubuntu](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#syntax-and-character-set) and 1 without any labels.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubu2
  labels:
    app: ubuntu
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ubu2
    image: ubuntu
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y && sleep 3000"]
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubu1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ubu1
    image: ubuntu
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y && sleep 3000"]
```

Then 2 deployments with service.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: nginx1
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx1
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello nginx1 > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"]
```

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx2
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx2
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: nginx2
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx2
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello nginx2 > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"]
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: frontend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: frontend
```

---

Another thing is [virtual service](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/) with mesh gateway, so it works only in the mesh, with 2 matches, 1 with sourceLabel which goes from pods with app: ubuntu label to nginx pod with v1 subset, and another match which goes to the nginx pod with v2 subset.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nginxvirt
spec:
  gateways:
  - mesh
  hosts:
  - nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - name: match-myuid
    match:
    - sourceLabels:
        app: ubuntu
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
        subset: v1
  - name: default
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
        subset: v2
```

---

And the last thing is **[DestinationRule](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/)** which take subsets from virtual service and sent it to proper nginx pod with label either nginx1 or nginx2

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: nginxdest
spec:
  host: nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      run: nginx1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      run: nginx2
```

---

**kubectl get pods --show-labels**

---

```
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     LABELS
nginx1-5c5b84567c-tvtzm   2/2     Running   0          23m     app=frontend,run=nginx1,security.istio.io/tlsMode=istio
nginx2-5d95c8b96-6m9zb    2/2     Running   0          23m     app=frontend,run=nginx2,security.istio.io/tlsMode=istio
ubu1                      2/2     Running   4          3h19m   security.istio.io/tlsMode=istio
ubu2                      2/2     Running   2          10m     app=ubuntu,security.istio.io/tlsMode=istio
```

---

**Results from ubuntu pods**

---

### Ubuntu with label

```
curl nginx/
Hello nginx1
```

---

### Ubuntu without label

```
curl nginx/
Hello nginx2
```

---

Let me know if that help.

Comment: Hi @FlyingBurrito, let me know if that worked for you or you need example with other namespace than default one.

Comment: Even this demo solution did not work for me.  I'm finally revisiting this issue, so I will report back once I have a solution.